# Can I use a value stored in a variable after an if statement with the loc method?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I created an if else statement to determine whether the min or max is the bigger difference and then stored the number to a variable.

```
findValue = 0.0

minAbs = abs(df[["numbers"]].min())
maxAbs = abs(df[["numbers"]].max())

if minAbs > maxAbs:
  findValue = minAbs
else:
  findValue = maxAbs

**df2=df.loc[df['numbers'] == findValue, 'day_related']**
df2
```

Python hates that I use findValue and not the actual number that it's set equal to in the statement with ** around it, but I thought these are interchangeable?

Comment: What do you mean by "Python hates that I use findValue"?

Comment: it gave me an error, I switched it up to see what minAbs contains and wrote it back, now it's a different error. minAbs (and maxAbs) are series in this format "numbers min", but I only want the min. How do I get rid of numbers?

Comment: Right now the if statement gives an error for trying to compare 2 series, instead of just the absolute value for min and max, pulled from a column in the dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df[["numbers"]]` creates a new dataframe with one column called `numbers`, so `df[["numbers"]].max()` isn't actually going to return a number; it's going to return a Series object with one item. `df["numbers"]` will return the actual `numbers` column so `.max()` and `.min()` will work as expected.

Change your code to this:

```
minAbs = abs(df["numbers"].min())
maxAbs = abs(df["numbers"].max())
```

...and then the rest of your code.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much, I actually figured it out when I noticed the double brackets (it's been a couple of semesters since learning pandas :D). The if statement also needed to be changed, because I'd want to find the negative value in the dataframe, not the absolute value (which would return nothing).